# Git with github - detaching a specifc file to a different repo/branch while being able to sync it with the main branch development

Tags: git, github

**The problem:** how to detach a specific file from a Github repo to seperate development Repo (or branch) while retaining the possibility to sync in from upstream (*git pull*_) and sync back (*pull request*) to the original repo.

**The use case:** I forked a [library](https://github.com/alonisser/WebcamSwiper) on GitHub and I'm working on various improvements, changes etc. my problem is that the forked repo is actually a complete demo site including the lib,I don't want the dem since I'm actually working with another demo site. **The optimal solution** for me would be being able to commit to the lib in my demo site and being able to retain the connection to the original repo without deleting the original demo site files or copying mine.

Yes, I guess I can do it with some make/build script copying the file all around but It doesn't look like an elegant (and maintainable) solution.

If this is the solution what would be the best tool for the job? I heard about git hooks but never actually used them. maybe TraviCI can come to the rescue? something else?

I'll be glad for any help

**Edit:** following some advice here I checked about [git remote](http://gitref.org/remotes/).  but this works repo wide, I need to seperate a specific file (or all but a speific file) that her and only her would keep the remote push/pull connection with the original repo.

**Another edit:** following a suggestion about using git *submodules*) I would like to clarify: *submodules* seems to solve half the problem - the half about seperating the lib from the demo site and actually, if I was the original maintainer I could do that, allowing others to fork only the lib without the demo site. since I'm not the maintainer then (If I understand correctly) seperating the lib to a submodule wouldn't solve the problems of keeping it synced with the original lib without syncing the rest of the demo site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the correct path to this problem. similiar to  **submodule** but a more specific to this problem: using a **[subbranch (filter-branch)](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subpath-out-into-a-new-repo)**.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not support what you want to do. Git has a lot of flexibility, but wants you to keep separate stuff in separate folders. If you write some shell scripts and encapsulate a lot of git commands you could make your plan work, but I would not recommend that.

What you can do is: put that other repo in its own folder, as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). If you also need that file somewhere else, symlink it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, what you are looking for is to have a remote repo. Check if it's something like this that you're looking for: http://gitref.org/remotes/

Comment: more specifically @Rodrigo-Neves can I add a remote just to a specific file in the repo?

Comment: ok I checked this, and elaborated in the question why I don't think this would work for me

Comment: I am afraid that is a bit too specific. I don't think you can get that level of granularity out of the box.